# SwiftUI - @FocusState as condition

Tags: swift, swiftui

For some reason, I wish to use `@FocusState` as a condition, but it doesn't work.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @FocusState private var mystate: Bool
    var body: some View {
        if mystate {
            Text("Hello")
        }

        Button(action: {
            print("before: \(mystate)")
            mystate.toggle()
            print("after: \(mystate)")
        }, label: {
            Text("Click Me")
        })
    }
}
```

And the console output is

```
before: false
after: false
```

Can anyone please explain why the `mystate` isn't changed when button get tapped? Thank you!

Comment: At the very least you need to be using the `focused()` function. Have a look at [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/focusstate).

Comment: Hi @par,
Thanks for your reply. Yes, I have used the `focused()` in the real project, that's why I need to use `@FocusState` rather than `@State`. The code snippet in the question is a highly simplified version to explain my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the FocusState needs something to focus on, without it it just changes itself to false (that’s why I added `TextField`) - and, it doesn’t change right away, but after it focuses something, therefore delay is needed.

This works for me:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @FocusState private var mystate: Bool
    var body: some View {
        if mystate {
            Text("Hello")
        }
        
        Button(action: {
            print("before: \(mystate)")
            mystate.toggle()
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(50)){
                print("after: \(mystate)")
            }
            
        }, label: {
            Text("Click Me")
        })
        TextField("myTextField", text: .constant("text")).focused($mystate)
    }
}
```